# Web.config - PayPal IPN Listener - HTTP error code 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: web-services, web-config, paypal-ipn

I am trying to get my PayPal IPN Listener to work on my Live environment, it works on Staging perfectly and the issue is something to do with the web.config file:

(http://pastebin.com/B8YhJEZK)

I am using "https://developer.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/devscr" and the Instant Payment Notification (IPN) simulator to test the web service however I am getting the following:

"IPN delivery failed. HTTP error code 500: Internal Server Error"

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read this announcment from PayPal in regards to some changes they made to their Instant Notification Service (ipn).

[enter link description here](https://www.x.com/content/bulletin-ip-address-expansion-paypal-services)

also, check your code and see if you have something similar to this:

```
$fp = fsockopen($host,"80",$err_num,$err_str,30);
```

And try changing it to something like this:

```
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://'.$host,"443",$err_num,$err_str,30);
```