# IPN delivery failed. HTTP error code 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: php, logging, error-handling, cpanel, paypal-ipn

I am creating a PHP file to communicate with Paypal's Instant Payment Notification (IPN). I have created an "ipn.php" file which uses an IPN Listener (with a file, "ipnlistener.php") to listen for a "POST" message from Paypal's server.

For this,  I have also created an "ipn_errors.log" file in the same folder as ipn.php. When I try  to access ipn.php from a web browser, it should throw up an error and log it to the ipn_errors.log file. The error shows up on the web browser but it isn't logged in the ipn_errors.log file. Also, on using Paypal Sandbox's Instant Payment Notification (IPN) simulator, it shows an error "IPN delivery failed. HTTP error code 500: Internal Server Error"

I believe this is because of a Permissions issue with the ipn.php and ipn_errors.log file. Can anybody tell me what permissions would be correct in this situation? I'm using cpanel to manage my website.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295435/web-config-paypal-ipn-listener-http-error-code-500-internal-server-error

Comment: @atmon3r This problem was in fact solved by changing the permission of the ipn.php file to 644. I believe the problems are similar but the solutions were certainly different.

Answer (score 0):

The server user needs write permission.  You need to add write permission to the group and change the file's group to the server user, or add write permission to the owner (and change the owner to the server user).

By server user, I mean the user under which apache is running.  On Debian/ubuntu, that user is www-data, on redhat, it's called apache.  Look around at the owner of other webserver-related files, and you ought to be able to find it somewhere as a file owner.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "server user". I can add write permission to the group but I don't understand how I can "change the file's group to the server user"

Comment: Oh, actually I'm using a Web Host Manager for cpanel. So will I have to ask the Internet reseller I'm using (which is GVO www.gogvo.com) to change the file's group to the server user?

Comment: Maybe?  I'm sorry, I haven't used cpanel.  If you're comfortable with the file being read by anyone on the system (hopefully it is outside your webroot, anyway) then you can just add write permission to the 3rd category of user permissions for 'other' users.  But that is essentially setting it to not have a permission check at all.  Use caution.